# Can not find module "json-schema" error when executing eslint

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, eslintrc

I'm facing a problem which I haven't found a solution on the internet yet. I found some similar cases but the solutions (mostly installing something or clearing the cache) doesn't work in my case.

I've installed the following packages (package.json) for my react project:

```
"devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
        "@ngtools/json-schema": "^1.1.0",
        "@types/react": "^16.9.35",
        "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.8",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.7",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.32.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.32.0",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
        "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.19.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.5.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.26.5",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
        "ts-loader": "^7.0.4",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/core": "^10.0.28",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.13.0",
        "formik": "^2.1.4",
        "moment": "^2.25.3",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
        "react-currency-format": "^1.0.0",
        "react-data-table-component": "^6.9.1",
        "react-datepicker": "^2.15.0",
        "react-flash-message": "^1.0.2",
        "react-intl": "^4.5.3",
        "react-loader-spinner": "^3.1.14",
        "react-moment": "^0.9.7",
        "react-pure-loaders": "^3.0.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "styled-components": "^5.1.0",
        "yup": "^0.28.5"
    }
```

Every time I execute the eslint to check a file I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load parser '@typescript-eslint/parser' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'json-schema'
```

I'm executing the command like this (on windows):

> node_modules.bin\eslint {path to my .tsx file}

Here's my `.eslintrc.js` (default generated airbnb styleguide):

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
    }
};
```

Does anyone have a solution for me? I've already tried to install several `json-schema` packages and already cleared the cache / node_modules folder. Sadly nothing helped so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encountered the same problem today. Seems there was an update.

In **package.json** downgrading:

```
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.32.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.32.0",
```

to:

```
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.25.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.25.0",
```

fixed the problem for now.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This just solved the problem for me, 8 years later. had to downgrade from 4.9.0 or something. @intelliJ how is this still a problem?

Answer (score -4):

rename the `.eslintrc.js` filename to `.eslintrc`

Comment: Your solution isn't an answer to my question.